# What is a simple image classification ANN architecture and a simple data set?

Tags: neural-network

I'm looking for a neural network architecture, which gives pretty good performance on an image classification challenge and is still simple to implement in a framework and also reasonably fast to train. Do you have suggestions?

I'm new the neural network implementation, and in the end, I'd like to do some "research-style" playing with it.

Moreover, a pointer to an image classification data set which is not too tough for a simple network would be great. However, not something like MNIST which is so easy that almost any classifier does a good job.

PS: Which neural network framework do you recommend if I'd like to modify the way the network is trained?

Answer (score 2):

I'd advice going through cs231n course, which covers this.

A simple but good architecture is using a feed forward net with one hidden layer and ReLU.

As for dataset - CIFAR-10 is good, if you don't like MNIST.

Tensorflow is quite easy to use framework.

Comment: But simple feedforward is not translation invariant? I'd like to work on non-centered images. Also single is unlikely to work as soon as images are not centered and I really need a hierarchy?

Comment: In this case it isn't exactly a simple dataset. One of possible solutions is to center the images while processing them. If you are sure you want to use non-centered images, fnn will perform badly indeed. So you can try CNN with several layers. Something like this: conv - relu - pool - dropout - conv - relu - pool - dropout - fully connected layer - dropout - fully connected layer.

Comment: Are you suggesting that single layer FNN on CIFAR would give OK results (also if I use grey-scale to avoid color effects)? It's not that I need non-centered, but I want to do something which doesn't diverge too much in approach from SOTA systems. If strides and pooling is for "centering" only, it would be fine.

Comment: FNN with a single hidden layer can get 50%+ accuracy on CIFAR. Using grey-scale should increase the accuracy. CNN with a structure, described by me, can give 70%+ accuracy.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good! I have no experience yet. Could you please also suggest dimensions for your layers so that I have a complete architecture? (or whatever I need to know to specify it exactly)

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but maybe it would be a good idea to try cs231n course to understand how all of this works? But if you wish, here are some examples (as I did in cs231n). Simple 2 layer FNN in numpy: https://github.com/Erlemar/cs231n_self/blob/master/assignment1/two_layer_net.ipynb (you can find the file with the net itself in the repo). CNN in tensorflow: https://github.com/Erlemar/cs231n_self/blob/master/assignment2/TensorFlow.ipynb